# Crop various image sizes to single size w/ ImageMagick

Tags: terminal, batch, imagemagick, crop

I have a large number of images of various sizes, all equal to or greater than 565x790. I would like to trim the edges of the image so that they are exactly that size. Is there a way to do this in a single command? It seems that crop requires defining how much to cut off, whereas I would like to trim whatever is necessary to get to that size, which will be slightly different for each image. I'd also like it to more-or-less equally distribute the trimming across the four edges of the image (à la -gravity?).

Do I have to mask with a centre of gravity and then trim the excess parts of the image? Or is there a simpler way to go about this?

Thanks!
D

(I'm using ImageMagick via Mac Terminal).

Answer (score 3):

So, I figured it out and learned a lot in the process:
1) My question was lazy and not specific enough -- apologies to Martin Zaske and anyone else who read it.
2) Crop basically does this automatically, but I did not play with it enough to realize it.
3) The command I wanted (for ImageMagick 6.9.9-11) is as follows:

```
    mogrify -gravity Center -crop 785x565+0+0 +repage *.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using irfanview. It has got batch conversion in its menu under file.

Go to batch conversion settings and advanced and you will have a window with many options, including crop. You even have a choice where to crop, for example to center your remaining image or rather to keep the top-left corner or whatever. irfanview is free.

In the crop, the sizes you fill in, is what you have left after the crop, not how much is cut off (otherwise there would be four boxes instead of two).

I advise to makes copies and play around a bit with a few photos until you got the hang of all the options.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that if this doesn't work... I'd much prefer to keep it in the command line, though, if possible.

Comment: please edit your question then and say what you prefer: windows command lines? Power Shell? Linux?

Comment: oops, did not see all your tags, never mind